# Копирование данных из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть 3 разных БД, назовем их SourceA, SourceB (источники) и Target (целевая).

В каждой из баз SourceA и SourceВ имеются идентичные по структуре таблицы (назовем Products) с набором столбцов: ID, Title, Price.
В БД Target Аналогичная таблица "Products", но с другой структурой:
ID, Title, Price, SourceID, SourceProductID.

Необходимо данные из таблиц, которые в SourceA и SourceB, вытянуть в таблицу Target. При этом чтобы в колонках SourceID отображалось название БД-источника, откуда вытянута строка (SourceA или SourceB), а в SourceProductID отображался ID (ключ) из таблицы источника.

Направьте на путь истинный, как можно решить эту задачу? Буду благодарен за любые советы.

Comment: `insert into Target.table(SourceID, ...) select 'A', .... from SourceA.table ...`

Comment: Не получилось. Подскажите, как синтаксически правильно совместить в insert into вставку результатов селекта и values ?

Comment: `values` вообще не нужно. вместо него select, который должен выдавать колонки в том порядке как они были бы в values